Why isn't $\mathbb{Q}$ the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ if every element satisfies this equation?
I can't understand this quote from Wikipedia:

Integers are the only elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ that are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, $\mathbb{Z}$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

To my understanding, the equation:
$$b\cdot\frac{a}{b}-a=0$$
Implies, by definition of an integral element, $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ whenever $q=\frac{a}{b}\wedge\{a,b\}\subset\mathbb{Z}$. Since every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a fraction, this trivially implies that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Did i understand something wrong?

That polynomial $bx-a\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not monic in general.

what is the additive inverse of a/b over Z?

I see. I just now notice the monic requirement of the integral element definition. @MattCalhoun an element of the integral closure of a subring $R$ doesn't generally have an inverse in $R$.

In the definition of integral closure, you need to look at monic polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.  So, for linear polynomials, they must be of the form $x-a=0$, which has the solution $x=a\in\mathbb{Z}$.  In your example, you're looking at $bx-a$, which isn't monic.
For higher degree polynomials, you might get non-integers which are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, but they won't be in $\mathbb{Q}$.  As such an example, $\sqrt{2}$ is a zero of the monic polynomial $x^2-2$, but it isn't in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks, i can see where my misunderstanding is now. It can be shown via rational root theorem that a monic polynomial will never match the denominator of a non-integer element in $\mathbb{Q}$
